# command line error exporting apk

Tags: android, apk, eclipse-adt

I imported windows projects into the same ADT version (the last version at the moment) but on Linux. The build is ok, but when I try to export signed or unsigned the APK, I receive an error "Command-line Error 132". Any tips? Just to be clear: I imported two projects but I've got problems only with one of them. This project depends on two google libraries I set with the new paths, indeed the build is ok.

Answer (score 0):

When you export your application you use the Android Tools create the .apk file.  According to this article

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60448

and from my own run in with that error the issue appears to be from Version 18 of the Android Build Tools.  I would recommend you use Version 17 or 19 of the build tools.  Just make sure that if version 19 doesn't work for you either to remove it and install version 17 since Eclipse tends to want to use the latest version of the tools to build your .apk.